# Windows 8 app XNA on two monitors with different resolutions

Tags: c#, windows-8, xna, monogame

I'm using Monogame to write an XNA game for Windows 8 app store. I'm also using a laptop hooked up to an external monitor. Naturally the resolution on my external monitor is much higher than my laptop's screen. When I drag the app from one screen to another the resolution on the view port changes.

In my constructor I'm using

```
 _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
 _graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
 _graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1366;
```

To set my viewport resolution. This makes the app to work fine when the application runs on either monitors, however dragging the app from one monitor to another changes the resolution on the GraphicsDeviceManager. Is there anyway to prevent this change?

Comment: What do you mean, the resolution changes? Does it increase, or is it just the window size that changes?

Comment: I'm testing one of my old XNA applications right now, on a Notebook with 1600x900 resolution and an external FullHD monitor. I'm dragging the window around, but the resolution doesn't change, only the (physical) size of the window, that's due to the difference in screen resolutions. The only real answer I can give you, is that maybe Monogame has a bug, since it's still in Beta and doesn't really use MS code (not even reverse-engineered). Though I wouldn't bet on that.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out

First I wrote a method that checks to see if the port resolution on the graphic device has changed

```
 private bool hasResolutionChanegd()
    {
        if ((GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width != ScreenManager.Instance.ScreenWidth) || (GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height != ScreenManager.Instance.ScreenHeight))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
           return false;
        }

    }
```

I call this method on every update

```
if (hasResolutionChanegd())
        {
             Debug.WriteLine("Resolution Change new width= " + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width +" new height="+ GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);

            _graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
            _graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1366;
            _graphics.ApplyChanges();
        }
```

This way every time the resolution changes on the Graphic Device Manager (when the user drags the app from one screen environment to another), the preferred resolution is enforced.

Comment: Instead of checking for viewport size changes on every update you might want to listen for CoreWindow's SizeChanged event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.sizechanged.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I get the same thing as the original poster, but with XNA, not MonoGame. When I drag the window between the two monitors, the resolution changes, but the ClientSizeChanged event is not (of course) triggered. The suggestion above to use the SizeChanged event is helpful but only for Windows8 the documentation says.

I appear to have fixed it by handling the Window.ScreenDeviceNameChanged event - I hooked it up to the same handler as the ClientSizeChanged.

I would have put this in as a comment to the original post, but I don't have enough "reputation" points for the system to let me.